# Allow application access to network drive files

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I've used Windows 8 for a couple years and to this day I have avoided one single annoyance but today I had enough and need to figure out a solution.

I have a network share, using OpenMediaVault, to store network files.  My Windows 8 has proper credentials saved in the credential manager, I can read/write/execute any file on my network drive.  The problem is, applications DO NOT have the same permissions.  Some will read and write, while others will not and it is driving me nuts.  For instance, today I used Acronis TrueImage software to backup a HDD onto the network drive.  It had no problem writing to it.  I then used the same application to restore the drive, it failed to recover unless I put the file on a local drive. I've seen this behavior with other applications, but they didn't have access period through I could browse my files perfectly fine.  There is some kind of permission issue which I can't resolve.  All files have read permission so why this discrepancy?